# Espresso not stubbing intent on older device/FirebaseTestLab

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I'm fairly new to writing Espresso tests, and I'm facing a kind of error that only happens in an older test device and in FirebaseTestLab, but not on the 3 other devices I'm testing with. These tests fail when they try to match the intent:

```
IntentMatcher: (has component: has component with: class name: is "com.mypackage.SeasonActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String and has extras: has bundle with: key: is "extra_title_id" value: is "h6Ck1q5TPs")

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
```

I wrote a few tests that check for intents when Espresso clicks certain views. I'm using intending/intended for that. For example:

```
private val result = Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null)

val matcher1: Matcher<Intent> = hasComponent(SeasonActivity::class.java.name)
val matcher2: Matcher<Intent> = hasExtra(Constants.PROGRAM_ID, 101010L)
val matcher3: Matcher<Intent> = hasExtra(TemplateView.PROGRAM_TITLE, "My Program Title")

intending(allOf()).respondWith(result)

// *** Clicking code ***

intended(allOf(
               matcher1,
               matcher2,
               matcher3))
```

The tests that pass consistently log this line in the console:

`I/MonitoringInstr: Stubbing intent Intent { cmp=com.xyz.MyActivity...`

...while the tests that fail in the older device and in FirebaseTestLab don't.

Does anyone know what am I missing?